# destroying the old instance of an activity in another task when a new instance is created in new task

Tags: android, android-activity

i have 3 activities A,B and C. The flow is like this:

`A->B->Home->C->B`.

I have used `singleTask` on activity B.
However this creates a side effect that when i do `A->B->Home->recent`, it returns to A instead of B. Activity B must be brought to foreground.

Also is there any way that i can destroy old B when new B is created??

Comment: Have you tried, `singleInstance` in combination of onNewIntent() ?

Comment: I have used singletask as singleinstance as singleinstance does not allo any other activity in its task.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Also is there any way that i can destroy old B when new B is created??"

Comment: i meant - when a new instance of B is created, can the old instance of B be destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

You could call `finish()` in your `onPause` callback. But you should handle rotations else your app will be exited on that event.